# Concatenate LPCTSTR for MessageBox

Tags: c++, winapi, tchar

How do I concatenate LPCTSTRs for the MessageBox?
The syntax in Java is like this

```
LPCTSTR str1 = "String2";
LPCTSTR str2 = "";
LPCTSTR str3 = "String1";
LPCTSTR finalMsg = "";

finalMsg = str1 + str2 + str3;
```

What is the syntax in C++/Win32?
Thanks!

Comment: The "syntax" is to use string classes, not pointers.  Also, your code would fail to compile if your application is Unicode.  An `LPCTSTR` is a pointer to either a narrow or wide string, depending on the build type.

Comment: You can't modify the memory, `finalMsg` points to because `LPCTSTR` is a pointer to `const TCHAR`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>

int main()
{
    LPCTSTR str1 = _T("String2");
    LPCTSTR str2 = _T("");
    LPCTSTR str3 = _T("String1");

    LPTSTR finalMsg = new TCHAR[_tcslen(str1) + _tcslen(str2) + _tcslen(str3) + 1];
    _tcscpy(finalMsg, str1);
    _tcscat(finalMsg, str2);
    _tcscat(finalMsg, str3);

    MessageBox(nullptr, finalMsg, _T("Message"), MB_OK);

    delete[] finalMsg;
}
```

Plan-B: Use the `std` string classes:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>

#include <string>

using tstring = std::basic_string<TCHAR>;

int main()
{
    tstring str1 = _T("String2");
    tstring str2 = _T("");
    tstring str3 = _T("String1");

    tstring finalMsg = str1 + str2 + str3;

    MessageBox(nullptr, finalMsg.c_str(), _T("Message"), MB_OK);
}
```

If you don't need to support ANSI-only versions of Windows, you can drop `TCHAR` and `...TSTR` altogether and use `std::wstring`, which is a template specialization of `std::basic_string` for `wchar_t`.

Comment: Hello, this works fine! Thank you! It's still my 3rd day with C++. Thanks for your help!

Comment: "It's still my 3rd day with C++". Then it would be probably better to work through a good(tm) textbook about C++ instead of playing with the WinAPI.

Comment: Not a great answer. Far better to use `wstring`, the `+` operator and then `c_str` when calling `MessageBox`. It's disappointing that this answer was accepted which makes no attempt to dispel the myth of `TCHAR` and continues using C style strings.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Agreed, although `std::wstring` is not necessarily correct either, since the whole thing with TCHAR is that it doesn't have to be a `wchar_t`.  Of course, in practice we all use `std::wstring` knowing that our projects only target one character type, and we bury our guilty conscience in order to get on with things. ;)  It would be more correct to use this approach and then invoke `MessageBoxW` explicitly.

Comment: @paddy No guilt at all in targeting Unicode. The guilt would be still using TCHAR as if it was still the 20th century. So yes `wstring` is correct here. And yes, invoke the W version explicitly. That's how I edited Jonathan's CW answer.

Comment: The edit is still problematic, continuing with `TCHAR` but calling `MessageBoxW`

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Was not done intentionally.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Might I ask why you removed the other link?

Comment: @Swordfish A history lesson is all it takes to understand why UTF-16 is used by Windows. Windows adopted UCS2 (as it was known) before UTF-8 had been invented.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Um. I know?

Comment: So why the snarky comment about MS using UTF-16. This hasn't been a terribly edifying process has it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan better?

Comment: Not really. Did you know that Java uses UTF16 natively.  I think Windows isn't really that special and the comment is just a needless and unhelpful distraction.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Know what? Edit the post to your precious liking. I'm done with the topic.

Comment: @Swordfish "*Might I ask why you removed the other link?*" - I didn't remove any link. The link didn't exist yet at the time I started making my edit. You were making edits around the same time I was, it likely just got lost during parallel edits.

Comment: "*Did you know that Java uses UTF16 natively*" - in fact, many programming languages have standardized on UTF-16 for their native string handling. UTF-8 is typically better for use in things like text storage, communication exchanges, etc but it is not very good for in-memory string processing. UTF-16 tends to be better for that instead. It tends to be a better balance between speed and overhead than other UTFs.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I don't know if you are the one downvoting everyone. You might feel that `TCHAR`s are ancient history. But it's just answering the question that was asked. For all I know, the OP is modifying older code and has to work with `TCHAR`s. Who downvotes for that?

Comment: @JonathanWood Well, your answer is a buffer overrun waiting to happen isn't it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Which I also covered in my answer, didn't I? I used to program old-style C, likely before you started programming. And it would be naive of you to assume I was getting buffer runs all over the place. Like I said, just answering the question asked.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `TCHAR` which is intended for code that can target Windows versions that do not support Unicode, i.e. Windows 98.

Make use of the standard library string classes to handle memory management and concatenation.

```
std::wstring str1 = L"String2";
std::wstring str2 = L"";
std::wstring str3 = L"String1"
std::wstring finalMsg = str1 + str2 + str3;
MessageBoxW(..., finalMsg.c_str(), ...);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `strcat()` to copy old C-style strings.

Or more precisely `_tcscat()` on most platforms to work with whatever character type you are using.

Be sure to preallocate your string buffer so that it's big enough to hold whatever the result is.

```
TCHAR buff[128];

_tcscpy(buff, str1);
_tcscat(buff, str2);
_tcscat(buff, str3);
```

Comment: That is better.